# TFS & Codeplex at the same time (source control)

Tags: tfs, codeplex, tfsintegrationplatform

Anyone an approach to this?

We have a commercial / inhouse project. SOME of the libraries are also dual available under LGPL on Codeplex. Not all source codde is supposed to go up there (not every checkin), but I would like to have regular uploads happening, preferably for "regular releases" / official releases. This will be triggered like weekly, whenever we have a more stable status on those public libraries.

Anyone an idea how to do that? My current approach is:

- Have two folder hierarchies mapped to the internal TFS and the external TFS location on Codeplex.
- Create a script that will check out on codeplex, copy all code over from the internal directory for those projects we publish
- Do a checkin on codeplex.

This script can the nbe triggered manually whenever we "feel like it". We will also upload the the generated dll's in this way (hopefully), as we do not distribute our official signature keys with the code.

Anyone a better idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best approch would be to use the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to Sync between the servers. You can start the sync any time you like and choose to sync all the changes since the last sync or just the slice off the top.

The TFS Integration Platform has a build in service or command line untility and a nice UI for configuring the sync.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  I think your approach is sound, but you may want to throw in a synchronization process with something like [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/index.html) or [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) where it will look at the two directories and update where appropriate.  I have some personal experience with SyncBack, which you can configure pretty extensively to tell it which files to copy, and which to ignore.

I'd set up the script to run on demand and on a scheduled basis.